# Why is my second database column being populated with 'none'?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create a database with three columns, URL which is the location of the data I am aiming to scrape, STATUS which is the ticker symbol of the stock, and STATUS which will be used to inform whether the data has been acquired yet, or not.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('tickers.db')
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE TAB(URL, TICKER, STATUS default "Not started");''')

for i in url_list:
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO TAB(URL) VALUES(?)",(i,))
    
for j in ticklist:
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO TAB(TICKER) VALUES(?)",(j,))

for row in conn.execute("SELECT URL, TICKER, STATUS from TAB"):
    print('URL={i}'.format(i=row[0]))
    print('TICKER={i}'.format(i=row[1]))
    print('STATUS={i}'.format(i=row[2]))
```

To populate the URL column I have used a list of URL's, similarly I am trying to the same thing with TICKER, however when I run the code, the column is only populated with 'none' for all rows.

**Output**

```
URL=https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/?q=$AACG&subreddit=wallstreetbets&metadata=true&size=0&after=1610928000&before=1613088000
TICKER=None
STATUS=Not started
URL=https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/?q=$AACIU&subreddit=wallstreetbets&metadata=true&size=0&after=1610928000&before=1613088000
TICKER=None
STATUS=Not started
```

Comment: Are you expecting the second INSERT operation to be filling in the values you didn’t provide in the first operation? Then that’s not how it works. INSERT always creates a new row, period. To add values to existing rows, you need to UPDATE them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to populate the columns, why not insert as rows directly?

Assuming `url_list` and `ticklist` are of equal length (and even if not) you can Try this:

```
for i, j in zip(url_list,ticklist):
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO TAB(URL, TICKER) VALUES(?,?)",(i,j))
```

That way you are adding the values as expected and not creating new rows with every `insert`

Comment: FWIW, `for t in zip(..): conn.execute(.., t)` would do… And you can probably reduce that further if you use bulk-execution.

Comment: Thank you for this, I had a lapse in judgement regarding the 'INSERT' operation, this makes more sense and works as needed.